# Should project.lock.json be checked in to repository or generated at build in vNext VSTS builds

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

I am trying to build a xproj project and used the prebuild.ps1 from https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5 to install dnx.

I then get a build error as seen in the picture and would like to know if it should be generated or checked in prior to building.

[image: build error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the prebuild.ps1 script and my project structure didnt match up. Fixing the paths used inside the scripts solved the problem.